# Set inital zoom using brush in D3

Tags: d3.js

In this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 how would you set an initial zoom for the brush based on the date?

I want it to load focussed on the last 12 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`extent` of the brush](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent) yourself `brush.extent([minVisibleDate, maxVisibleDate])` before the graph is drawn, and then call `brushed()` and [`brush.event(context.select('g.x.brush'))` at the end](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_event) to set the zoom level and draw the `brush` respectively.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Just found extent() and now trying to find the x domain for the max date - 1 day. Will update soon.

Comment: So I have managed to get the start and end range extent but the focus chart goes blank and there is no brush extent shown when I include .call(brush.event) on g.x.brush. Similar to how it is done here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537

Comment: Here is the code:`context.append("g").attr("class", "x brush").call(brush.extent([x2(startDate), x2(endDate)])).call(brush.event)`

Comment: Found the issue. I was mapping the dates to the domains to try and get the x in the range rather than just using the dates! `context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush.extent([startDate, endDate]))
        .call(brush.event)`